# How the element is accessible after .remove() method?

Tags: jquery

when we use `$("selector").remove()` on any element , it will immediately
removed , and `$("selector").remove()` is a synchronous method , so next statement will be executed when the element is removed. But in my case the element is still accessible after removing it.

```js
$("#click1").on("click", function() {
  $(this).remove();
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click1">
  click on me
</button>
```

My question is , if the element is remove(out of dom) How  i can still access it by  `$(this).text()` ?
 any ideas?

UPDATE:

In any other case , this not happens

```js
$("#click1").on("click", function() {
  $(this).remove();
  alert($(this).text());
});
$("#click2").on("click", function() {
  $("#click1").remove();
  alert($("#click1").text());

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click1">
  click on me
</button>
<button id="click2">
  click on me too
</button>
```

Now the second button , remove the element immeditlly and i am no longer , access the element , (not even after very little time)

Comment: `remove()` method just takes element out of DOM

Comment: That's expected behaviour. `$.fn.remove()` removes element from DOM, not any reference on it

Comment: Isn't it great that objects don't pop out of existence because you took them out of the page?

Comment: Following edit, it is because `$("#click1")` is searching in the DOM and there the element doesn't exist anymore so it returns empty jq set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery uses `removeChild` internally, and the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) states

> The removed child node still exists in memory, but is no longer part
>   of the DOM.
>
> ...you may reuse the
>   removed node later in your code,
>
> ...assuming your code has not kept any other reference to the node elsewhere, it will immediately become unusable and irretrievable, and will usually be automatically deleted from memory after a short time.

In your event handler, `this` still references the node, so it's not deleted from memory, and can be used as long as you have a reference to the node

When you once again do `$("#click1")` jQuery uses `.getElementById` to fetch the element from the DOM, but it's no longer in the DOM, it has been removed.

Answer (score 3):

In general, objects exist as long as there's an existing reference to them.

In your first example:

```
$(this).remove();
alert($(this).text());
```

...you still have a reference to the object after you remove it (in `this`), so the object still exists and you can get its text (its child nodes still exist, because it has references to them).

In your second example:

```
$("#click1").remove();
alert($("#click1").text());
```

....after removing it from the document, you try to find it by looking it up in the document. It's not in the document anymore, so it's no great surprise you don't find it.